# Keeping all white spaces as tokens

Tags: python, spacy

I have a question about whether there is a way to keep single white space as an independent token in spaCy tokenization.

For example if I ran:

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc = nlp("This is easy.")
toks = [w.text for w in doc]
toks
```

The result is

```
['This', 'is', 'easy', '.']
```

Instead, I would like to have something like

```
['This', ' ', 'is', ' ', 'easy', '.']
```

Is there are a simple way to do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

spaCy exposes the token's whitespace as the `whitespace_` attribute. So if you only need a list of strings, you could do:

```
token_texts = []
for token in doc:
   token_texts.append(token.text)
   if token.whitespace_:  # filter out empty strings
       token_texts.append(token.whitespace_)
```

If you want to create an actual `Doc` object out of those tokens, that's possible, too. `Doc` objects can be [constructed](https://spacy.io/api/doc#init) with a `words` keyword argument (a list of strings to add as tokens). However, I'm not sure how useful that would be.

Comment: Cool. That's what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you want the whitespaces in the `doc` object:

```
import spacy
from spacy.tokens import Doc

class WhitespaceTokenizer(object):
    def __init__(self, vocab):
        self.vocab = vocab

    def __call__(self, text):
        words = text.split(' ')
        res = [' '] * (2 * len(words) - 1)
        res[::2] = words
        return Doc(self.vocab, words=res)

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
nlp.tokenizer = WhitespaceTokenizer(nlp.vocab)
doc = nlp("This is easy.")
print([t.text for t in doc])
```

Comment: This is also useful. Thank you so much!